# Topology: neighborhoods and connectedness?

Tags: general-topology

I have a question on neighborhood concepts.

TS = $(X, \tau), X = \{a,b\}, \tau = \{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{b\},X\}$

$a$ is in two neighborhoods $\{\{a\},X\}$, but at the same time $a$ is an isolated point and should have no connectedness or nearness to other points.  For instance, a disconnected space is defined $\exists x,y\in\tau ((x \cap y) = \emptyset \land (x \cup y) = X)$, which is true for $(X,\tau)$.

**Question** I'm a bit confused, do the neighborhoods define the connectedness of the points in them?

I think my conceptual understanding may be wrong on connectedness and the neighborhoods.  If connectedness is among points in a neighborhoods, then the trivial topology has a neighborhood $X$ where all points would be connected.  Appreciate your guidance.

Comment: A singleton is always connected. In the trivial topology these are the connected components. For example, the topology of $\Bbb Q$ (inherited from $\Bbb R$) also makes the singletons the connected components, however, any neighborhood of a point has to contain an interval around that point.

Comment: @Berci Im confused on connectedness among points.  If I define any points, due to the requirement of closure by unions and intersections, it seems that all points will be connected at least from a union.  Am I missing a concept?

Comment: you’re missing the fact that $x$ and $y$ have to be non-empty in your definition of a disconnected space. otherwise every top space is disconnected.

Comment: A point is not connected but a set can be connected or not, depending on its topology. It’s a global property of a set. You cannot tell it by neighbourhoods alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connectedness is a property of spaces, really. Your $X$ in the given topology is *not* connected because we can write $X = \{a\} \cup \{b\}$ which is a disjoint union of non-empty open sets, and this "witnesses" the disconnectedness of $X$: it has at least two "open pieces" that are "independent" (disjoint).

The subset $\{a\}$, an open neighbourhood of $a$ is connected (as we can never write a singleton as a union of two non-empty pieces at all, let alone relatively open pieces). Ditto for $\{b\}$. So this small space is on the hand had disconnected and also locally connected. This is always the case for non-trivial discrete spaces like $X$.

The space $X=\{a,b\}$ with the trivial topology $\{\emptyset,X\}$ is connected (we don't have only two open sets, but one is empty, so we cannot write it as a union of two disjoint open non-empty sets. It's also locally connected as any point only has one neighbourhood, i.e. $X$, which is connected.

Comment: My question is regarding a disconnected space in the example and why a disconnected point shares the same neighborhood with other points. I’m confused by that being disconnected and still being in a neighborhood with different points.

Comment: @Nick neighbourhoods don’t determine connectedness, really. Like I said, that’s a global property.

Comment: @Nick there is no such thing as a "disconnected point" which "shares" the same neighbourhood with other points. That's just nonsense.